# Comparing two columns and highlighting if the specified value is not available

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have two columns A and B, If A Column have the specific value "High" then the corresponding cell in B Column should contain the Date (dd/mm/yyyy)value otherwise if date value is not available the cell should be highlighted as Red. I am new to this macro and I am not able to find the logic for this.

Comment: Use [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) there is no need for VBA here.

Comment: can this be done using vba

Comment: Yes, but it makes no sense to re-invent the wheel if there is a buit-in tool for this in Excel. If you need to do this with VBA do some research try something on your own and come back with your code. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this isn't a comment, but I don't have sufficient rep.

I'm a little unclear how dates are populated in column B. Is this something we can take as given or are you assigning dates somehow? It might help if you could share a bit more about the structure of the sheet, maybe some "dummy data"?

That said, this sounds like a straightforward case of loops + conditional statements. I doubt this will work for you out of the box, but you could try nested For loops over columns A and B à la:

```
For Each cell in Range("A:A")
  If cell.Value = "High" Then
      If IsEmpty(Range("B"&cell.Row)) Then       'IsEmpty tests whether the cell is empty, you may need to change this if the cell has some other value in it
        Range("B"&cell.Row).Interior.Color = 255 '255 corresponds to the color red
      End If
  End If
Next cell
```

I agree with Pᴇʜ though, you don't actually need VBA for this at all. You can apply conditional formatting using a formula for the rule and then use a formula like this for the cells in column B:

```
=IF(A2="High",IF(ISBLANK(B2),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

Then just make sure you apply the formula to all the rows you care about.